# line on graph is horizontal but shouldn't be- can't figure out why

Tags: python, sage

I'm testing bifurcations with 2 different equations and values and one came out great but even when i copy and pasted the exact same thing for the second part and just switched out the equation and 1 value, y=0 on the horizontal axis.

here is the code for the first part that came out correctly:

```
assume(x>=0)
assume(x,"real")
rhigh = 1
rlow = 0.99
accuracy=0.000001
r=0.45
n=0
while abs(rhigh-rlow)>accuracy:
    r=(rhigh+rlow)/2
    n=n+1
    if len(solve((x^2)/(1+x^2)-r*x==0,x))==2:
        break
    elif len(solve((2*x^2)/(1+x^2)-r*x==0,x))==1:
        rhigh=r
    else:
        rlow=r
print(r)
print(n)
plot(r*x,(x,0,5))+plot((2*x^2)/(1+x^2)-r*x,(x,0,5),axes_labels=["x","values of x'"],color="cyan")
```

[image]

here is what I did for the second part (notice one value change and one equation change):

```
assume(x>=0)
assume(x,"real")
rhigh = 1
rlow = 0.7
accuracy=0.000001
r=0.45
n=0
while abs(rhigh-rlow)>accuracy:
    r=(rhigh+rlow)/2
    n=n+1
    if len(solve((x^2)/(1+x^2)-r*x==0,x))==2:
        break
    elif len(solve((1.5*x^21+x^2)-r*x==0,x))==1:
        rhigh=r
    else:
        rlow=r
print(r)
print(n)
plot((r*x),(x,0,5))+plot(((1.5*x^21+x^2)-r*x),(x,0,5),axes_labels=["x","values of x'"],color="pink")
```

[image]

I can't figure out why the blue line is on the horizontal axis instead of similar to the first picture. Basically, I can't figure out the part of the code that is causing that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't know why. However, if you add `ymax=7` as the parameter of the second plot. it gives you the correct graph.